# Firebase Analytics DllNotFoundException

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, firebase-analytics

I am trying to integrate Firebase into Unity but I am getting an error.

Here is my error message

```
DllNotFoundException: App-4.5.2
at (wrapper managed-to-native) Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalyticsPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper:SWIGRegisterExceptionCallbacks_FirebaseAnalytics (Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalyticsPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalyticsPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalyticsPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalyticsPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalyticsPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalyticsPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalyticsPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalyticsPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalyticsPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalyticsPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.Analytics.Fireb
```

---

I found some references using Google. Many people said `Play Service Resolver` -> `Android` -> `Setting` then choose `Force Resolve`. I tried this but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The problem was that i solved Play Service dependencies when the build was configurated in x86. When i changed architecture (to ARMv7) the dependencies did not refreshed in Plugins/Android.

To check this, you can open firebase app aar located in Plugins/Android (with winrar):

```
com.google.firebase.firebase-app-unity-4.5.2 -> jni -> [architecture folder] -> libApp-4.5.2.so
```

For example:

```
com.google.firebase.firebase-app-unity-4.5.2 -> jni -> armeabi-v7a -> libApp-4.5.2.so
```

To solve this you must **force** Play Services Resolution located in:

```
Assets->Play Services Resolver->Android Resolver->Force Resolve
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was caused because I used different versions of **Firebase Messaging** and **Firebase Analytics**. Problem was solved after updating all used sdks to **same version**.